# getting two consicutive value from file in java

Tags: java, file, csv, stream, filereader

I am working with a csv file, and I want to extract two values in specific positions from each and every row.

The csv input file looks like this:

```
a, b, c, d
12,32,45,76
23,45,77,56
32,34,49,28
73,92,26,68
73,36,77,26
```

For example I want the two consecutive values from the 3rd position (column c) from every row at the same time, so (45, 77), (49, 26), (77, ???)…

After getting those 2 values, I want to do some calculation on them and store them back.I am working on []2X1 size matrix multiplication. for that reason i need two consecutive value at a time.

```
package rotation.pkg45;import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Rotation45 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String filename = "bank-full2.csv";

        File file = new File(filename);
        BufferedWriter writer = null;

        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("bank2test1.csv"));     
            double a1 = 0.866025;
            double a2 = 0.5;
            double a3 = -0.5;
            double a4 = 0.866025;
            double b1;
            double b2;
            double c1;
            double c2;        

            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
            inputStream.next(); 
            Scanner inputStreamm = new Scanner(file);
            inputStreamm.next();         

            while (inputStreamm.hasNext()) {  
                String data = inputStreamm.next(); //read each line and store in data
                String[] values = data.split(","); //every line splited with " ; " and store each attribute in string list

                double first = Double.parseDouble(values[2]);


/*NoSuchElementException*/String data1 = inputStreamm.next(); //read comming nextline for second value and store in data1
                String[] values1 = data1.split(","); 
                //inputStream.next();         
                double second = Double.parseDouble(values1[2]);

                c1 = ((a2 * second) + (a1 * first));
                c2 = ((a3 * first) + (a4 * second));
                values1[2] = String.valueOf(c2);
                values[2] = String.valueOf(c1);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                //String newData = sb.toString();
                for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    sb.append(values[i]);
                    if (i < values.length - 1) {
                        sb.append(",");
                    }
                }
                sb.append("\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < values1.length; i++) {
                    sb.append(values1[i]);
                    if (i < values.length - 1) {
                        sb.append(",");
                    }
                }
                //get the new string
                //System.out.println(sb.toString());

                writer.write(sb.toString()+"\n");
            }
            writer.close();
            inputStreamm.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Rotation45.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

i am getting error like nosuchelement exception at mention in my code...

Comment: Always post the exact error message with information on which line it occurs, not "error like..."

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:906)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1415)
    at javaapplication55.JavaApplication55.main(JavaApplication55.java:69)  at I mention in my code in comment-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using a BufferedReader instead of the scanner to read the datas. Since your code is trying to read the whole line via the scanner and then split it, you can do that in a much easier way using a `BufferedReader`and calling its `readLine()`method.

So the changes I brought to your code are simply a replacement of the use of the scanner by a use of the BufferedReader. **I have not checked the computing** but it seems to me that it is working fine.

Here is an image of the result that I get:

[image: result of computations]

Also since your while loop is based on the scanner I changed that too.The while loop that I am using checks that both lines are not null (reading them at the same time the while condition is being assessed)

The last point regarding your code is that on the BufferedWriter you have a `newLine()`method that inserts a portable equivalent of line skeep (the `\n` in your code)

Here is the code. Execute it and check that it is working fine.

```
public class Rotation45 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String filename =     "bank-full2.csv";

        File file = new File(filename);
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {

            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new      FileWriter("bank2test1.csv"));     
            double a1 = 0.866025;
            double a2 = 0.5;
            double a3 = -0.5;
            double a4 = 0.866025;
            double b1;
            double b2;
            double c1;
            double c2;        

            String line1= null;
            String line2 = null;
            // Skeeps the head line
            reader.readLine();

            String currentLine = null;

            while (  ((line1 = reader.readLine())!= null) && ((line2 =     reader.readLine()) != null)       ) {

                String[] values = line1.split(","); 

                double first = Double.parseDouble(values[2]);

                String[] values1 = line2.split(","); 

                double second = Double.parseDouble(values1[2]);

                c1 = ((a2 * second) + (a1 * first));
                c2 = ((a3 * first) + (a4 * second));
                values1[2] = String.valueOf(c2);
                values[2] = String.valueOf(c1);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    sb.append(values[i]);
                    if (i < values.length - 1) {
                        sb.append(",");
                    }
                }
                sb.append("\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < values1.length; i++) {
                    sb.append(values1[i]);
                    if (i < values.length - 1) {
                        sb.append(",");
                    }
                }

                writer.write(sb.toString());
                writer.newLine();
            }
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            reader.close();

        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Rotation45.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,      null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does the following :

```
inputStream.next();
while (inputStreamm.hasNext()) {               
   inputStreamm.next();
   ...
   inputStreamm.next();
   ...
}
```

Which means it will perform a odd amount of reads (`2*n + 1`). But your input clearly consist of a even amount of data. That's why you get the exception.

It is unclear how you want to handle the case of `(77, ???)` but to detect it you should call `hasNext()` once again in the loop.

```
inputStream.next();
while (inputStreamm.hasNext()) {               
   inputStreamm.next();
   ...
   if(inputStreamm.hasNext())
       inputStreamm.next();
       ...
   else
       //take care of special case
   ...
}
```